# Using an adr-file, how to change format of the address?

Tags: letters, scrlttr2, addresses

I'm up to use LaTeX for writing my letters, invoices, other stuff and I'm nearly finished with setting up my templates using the KOMA class `scrlttr2`. One thing remains...

I got an address-file where I put my contacts/clients like this:

```
\adrentry{name}{surname}{address}{phone}{F1}{F2}{comment}{LABELNAME}
```

Then I use it in my main `.tex` file:

```
...
\input{contacts.adr}
\begin{letter}{\LABELNAME}
....
```

This is working pretty well, but I want to have a special formatting. Depending on F1, where I put the gender of my contact, I want to have "Mr." or "Mrs." or if not present "Company" right before the name. And I can't figure out how that could be done. I've read a lot of examples showing how to generate a bulk letter but can't transform this to my case of just formatting **one** address instead of them all.

But maybe that points someone else in the right direction so he can help me out?

```
\renewcommand*{\adrentry}[8]{
  \begin{letter}{#2 #1\\#3}
    \if #5m \opening{Dear Mr. #1,} \fi
    \if #5w \opening{Dear Mrs. #1,} \fi
    Some text in which the arguments can be used as well.
    \closing{Bye,}
  \end{letter}
}
```

So what I want to achieve is something that **might** look like this (It's not working, I know):

```
\renewcommand*{\adrentry}[8]{
  \if #5m Mr. #2 #1\\ \fi
  \if #5w Mrs. #2 #1\\ \fi
  \if #5c #2\\#6\\ \fi % It's a company, #6 states the contact person
  #3
}
```

Any ideas, links, etc.?

Oh boy, I hope you can follow and thanks in advance!

---

### EDIT:

It follows a minimal working example showing the state that I have, not including the feature described above (since I o not know how to do that ;)

The address file (contacts.adr) including a person and a company:

```
\adrentry{Cool Company Inc.}{}{Companystreet 21\\12345 Elsewhere}{}{c}{Mr. Tim Tailor}{}{CCI}
\adrentry{Meier}{Michael}{Meierstreet 34\\45636 Nowhere}{}{m}{}{}{MEIER}
```

The tex file using scrlttr2:

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,
    version=last,
    enlargefirstpage,
    fontsize=11pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% global koma vars
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Myname}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49\,123\,45678910}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{mymail@gmail.com}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Max Myname, Some Street 12, 012345 Somewhere}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Some Street 12\\012345 Somewhere}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{subject}{The subject}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{place}{Dresden}
\setkomavar{yourmail}{1.1.2013}
\setkomavar{yourref}{76/54/321}
\setkomavar{myref}{123/456/789}

\input{contacts.adr}
\begin{letter}{\MEIER}
\opening{Dear Mr. Meier}
\lipsum[7]
\closing{Sincerely yours}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The above produces

```
Michael Meier 
Meierstreet 34 
45636 Nowhere
```

and

```
Cool Company Inc. 
Companystreet 21 
12345 Elsewhere
```

But I'd like it to produce

```
Mr.
Michael Meier 
Meierstreet 34 
45636 Nowhere
```

and

```
Cool Company Inc.
Mr. Tim Tailor 
Companystreet 21 
12345 Elsewhere
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add signature, your user name is automatically added to your post. If you can, please also package your code in a [Minimal working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/19384) which can be compiled by anyone.

Comment: Sure I'll do! Sorry...

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about :-) We all learn from the experience of others on this site.

Comment: Added. Yeah, hopefully **I**'ll learn too! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question; I solved it by changing `\addrentry` and adding something innocuous to `\begin{letter}`, that will do nothing if a subsequent `\makeopening` command doesn't follow.

In the usual `\addentry` command, the last argument is used to build a control sequence that stores the address lines. I add also the building of an opening line, which for `MEIER` is stored in `\opening@MEIER`. This command is called by `\makeopening` (using the hook added before).

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,
    version=last,
    enlargefirstpage,
    fontsize=11pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xpatch}
%%% Patch the relevant scrlttr macros
\makeatletter
% at the end of \begin{letter}{<name>} store the <name>
\xapptocmd\letter{\gdef\this@letter@to{#2}}{}{}

% this seems complicated, but is needed to strip off
% the backslash from the argument to `\begin{letter}`
% Don't use `\makeopening` if the argument to `\begin{letter}`
% is not obtained via the `.adr` file

% we need to get \opening@MEIER from the fact that
% \this@letter@to expands to \MEIER so we first expand
% \this@letter@to, then \string, so that \@gobble will
% remove the backslash
\newcommand\makeopening{%
  \@nameuse{%
    opening@%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \@gobble\expandafter\string\this@letter@to}}

% modify \addrentry to define an opening and
% the address lines as desired
\newif\if@company
\renewcommand\addrentry[9]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty
  \else
    \@companyfalse
    \if#5m%
      \@namedef{opening@#9}{\opening{Dear Mr.\ #1,}}%
    \else
      \if#5w%
        \@namedef{opening@#9}{\opening{Dear Mrs.\ #1,}}%
      \else
        \@namedef{opening@#9}{\opening{Sirs,}}%
        \@companytrue
      \fi
    \fi
    \def\@tempa{#2}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty
      \if@company
        \@namedef{#9}{#1\\#6\\#3}%
      \else
        \@namedef{#9}{#1\\#3}%
      \fi
    \else
      \if@company
        \@namedef{#9}{#2\\#6\\#3}%
      \else
        \@namedef{#9}{#2 #1\\#3}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother



% global koma vars
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Myname}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49\,123\,45678910}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{mymail@gmail.com}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Max Myname, Some Street 12, 012345 Somewhere}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Some Street 12\\012345 Somewhere}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{subject}{The subject}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{place}{Dresden}
\setkomavar{yourmail}{1.1.2013}
\setkomavar{yourref}{76/54/321}
\setkomavar{myref}{123/456/789}

\input{meier.adr}
\begin{letter}{\MEIER}
\makeopening
\lipsum[7]
\closing{Sincerely yours}
\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{\CCI}
\makeopening
\lipsum[7]
\closing{Sincerely yours}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Here are the two letters (relevant parts only)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Damn it, I'm totally blown away! It's working like a charm! Even though it really looks complicated at least to me. But that is imo because the way of texing compared to programming in general is complete different but I like to think in those latter paradigms.
Sorry for not voting your answer up, I'm not allowed to (yet).

Comment: @aaki Keep up with the good questions and you'll be soon. And, who knows, also with good answers, too!