# adrentry modifications with expl3?

Tags: expl3, latex3, addresses

I am trying to use and .adr file to store the addresses for letters.

I found the very powerful answer here:
[Using an adr-file, how to change format of the address?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98896/using-an-adr-file-how-to-change-format-of-the-address/98935#98935)

It works great and I was even able to adapt it to my usecase:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xpatch}
%%% Patch the relevant scrlttr macros
\makeatletter
% at the end of \begin{letter}{<name>} store the <name>
    \xapptocmd\letter{\gdef\this@letter@to{#2}}{}{}
    
    % this seems complicated, but is needed to strip off
    % the backslash from the argument to `\begin{letter}`
        % Don't use `\makeopening` if the argument to `\begin{letter}`
    % is not obtained via the `.adr` file
    
    % we need to get \opening@MEIER from the fact that
    % \this@letter@to expands to \MEIER so we first expand
    % \this@letter@to, then \string, so that \@gobble will
    % remove the backslash
    \newcommand\makeopening{%
        \@nameuse{%
            opening@%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            \@gobble\expandafter\string\this@letter@to}}
    
    % modify \addrentry to define an opening and
    % the address lines as desired
    \renewcommand\addrentry[9]{%
        \def\@tempa{#1}%
        \ifx\@tempa\@empty
        \else
        \@namedef{opening@#9}{\opening{#5}}%    % define opening phrase
        \@namedef{#9}{#2 #1\\#3}%               % re-define the address field (because of renewcommand)
        \fi
    }
\makeatother
    
% global koma vars
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Myname}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Max Myname, Some Street 12, 012345 Somewhere}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Some Street 12\\012345 Somewhere}

\begin{document}
    
    \setkomavar{subject}{The subject}
    \setkomavar{date}{\today}
    \setkomavar{place}{Dresden}
    
    \input{test_adressen.adr}
    \begin{letter}{\MaxMustermann}
        \makeopening
        \lipsum[7]
        \closing{Sincerely yours}
    \end{letter}
    
    \begin{letter}{\MariaMustermann}
        \makeopening
        \lipsum[7]
        \closing{Sincerely yours}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

With test_addressen.adr being:

```
\addrentry{Mustermann}
    {Max}
    {\bigskip Musterstraße 12\\12345 Musterstadt}
    {(1234)~1~23~45~67}
    {Guten Tag Herr Mustermann,}
    {frei2}
    {frei3}
    {default selection for address}
    {MaxMustermann}

\addrentry{Mustermann}
    {Maria}
    {\bigskip Musterstraße 12\\12345 Musterstadt}
    {(1234)~1~23~45~67}
    {Sehr geehrte Frau Mustermann,}
    {frei2}
    {frei3}
    {default selection for address}
    {MariaMustermann}
```

I would like to use it in my setup, however, because of the `\usepackage` I cannot use it in an .lco file. Is there a possibility to implement this without `xparse` and / or with `expl3` which I now understand more than the low level latex2e commands like `\this@letter@to` which are still a mystery to me?

Comment: change `\usepackage` to `\RequirePackage`.

Comment: @Skillmon: that does not change anything. You can also not use `\RequirePackage` in an .lco file if you still want to be able to use it in `\LoadLetterOption` after `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without `xpatch`.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% at the end of \begin{letter}{<name>} store the <name>, which is #2,
% but without the backslash
\NewCommandCopy{\originalletter}\letter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\letter}{O{}m}
 {
  \originalletter[#1]{#2}
  \tl_gset:Nx \g_mrcarnivore_name_tl { \cs_to_str:N #2 }
 }
\tl_new:N \g_mrcarnivore_name_tl

% Don't use `\makeopening` if the argument to `\begin{letter}`
% is not obtained via the `.adr` file

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeopening}{}
 {
  \use:c { opening@ \tl_use:N \g_mrcarnivore_name_tl }
 }
% modify \addrentry to define an opening and
% the address lines as desired
\renewcommand\addrentry[9]
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
   {
    \cs_set:cpn {opening@#9}{\opening{#5}} % define opening phrase
    \cs_set:cpn {#9}{#2~#1\\#3}            % re-define the address field
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
    
% global koma vars
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Myname}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Max Myname, Some Street 12, 012345 Somewhere}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Some Street 12\\012345 Somewhere}

\begin{document}
    
\setkomavar{subject}{The subject}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{place}{Dresden}
\input{test_adressen.adr}

% first letter

\begin{letter}{\MaxMustermann}

\makeopening

\lipsum[7]

\closing{Sincerely yours}

\end{letter}

% second letter
    
\begin{letter}{\MariaMustermann}

\makeopening

\lipsum[7]

\closing{Sincerely yours}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the translation of your solution from ten years ago into expl3! Also thanks for finding a solution without the need for `usepackage`! There is still one strange behaviour: the addressee name is written without a space between the first and last name. This is most likely because of the `ExplSyntaxOn`. It will be fixed with `\cs_set:cpn {#9}{#2\ #1\\#3}`. Or would you think using `~` or `\nobreakspace` instead of `\` is better?

Comment: Also: Why do you copy the `\letter` command? It breaks without the copy, but I do not understand why...

Comment: @mrCarnivore Because I want to *change* its work, but keeping the name. I fixed the missing space.

Comment: Ah, I get it. You copy its previous behavior to `\originalletter` and then redefine it with its original behavior (by calling `\originalletter`) and adding something else to it. Great! What not works in your solution is that now you cannot use it any more with letters without addressfile but with normal explicit addressee and opening command. Then you get an error of `Undefined control sequence \opening{Hello}`...  But you never redefine or undefine `\opening`... ?

Comment: @mrCarnivore The comments explain you must not use `\makeopening` in those cases.

Comment: I did of course obey the comment and used the normal `\begin{letter}{Max Mustermann} \opening{\Hallo}` instead. But it breaks as I wrote above...

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I did use `\opening` instead of `makeopening` but I wrongly used `\Hallo` instead of `Hallo`...